# Setting somethig equal to the value of a known method with known contents results in undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, object, hapi

I have a piece of code that generates objects that deliver functions, but the function variable pulled from the first variable only comes up as undefined.

Early in the code, an object is defined to return an object containing functions, the function in this case being something like:

```
/* Pulls in and sets up libraries like hapi, axios, lodash, joi, await-to-js */
/* CODE */
module.exports = {
 routes: () => {  // This is in a set location used by a well established library
  
     return [
       {
          'handler': function (a, b) { return ((a - b)/12) }
       }
     ]
  }
}
```

An object is created by a function in my testing scripts:

```
/* Pulls in and libraries like chai, chai expect, chance, to, sinon, proxyquire, and sinonChai */
/* CODE */
describe ('function fetcher', () => {
  it('should return a function', async () => {
    let testModule = proxyquire('../path-to-file/', {})
    let myObject =  await testModule.routes() // The library function that grabs the routes
    console.debug(typeof(myObject))
    console.debug(myObject)
    let result = myObject.handler
    console.debug(typeof(result))
    console.debug(result)
    result(chance.Number, chance.Number)
    /* More processing */
  })
})
```

And it returns

```
/* OUTPUT */
object
{
   handler: [Function: handler]
}
undefined
undefined
```

My goal is to get this line to work:

```
/* CODE */
return result(a, b)
```

Comment: `routes` seems to return an array of objects in the code sample, yet in your code it looks like it's a singular object (`myObject` is an object in your code, but following the code provided should be an array). Are you sure the test case code you provided is accurate? Alternatively, can you try accessing handler using a string f.e. `routes['handler']` to see if that changes anything?

Comment: @nbokmans That doesn’t change anything.

Comment: @deceze I don't see how that is an answer to my question? Seems relevant to me.

Comment: The code output is accurate. It's returning an object. I can only assume the shift is part of the hapi library or proxyquire libraries in action.